# Android: Support multiple API level on single APK for Bluetooth App

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have developed an App which use bluetooth function on Jelly Bean(Android 4.3). I noticed Lollipop's bluetooth class has a set of different methods. When I run my App on Lollipop, it failed.

I have learned that I can add code to support different API level in runtime, like:

```
private void startScanBluetooth(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // Method supported in Lollipop
        mLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
    }
    else {
        // Method for older API level
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}
```

My code has a **BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback** which is in my Activity Class but outside any method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);
    setContentView(R.layout.device_list);

    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    //....
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //String targetDevice = MainActivity.targetDevice.getText().toString();
                                //if(targetDevice==null || targetDevice.length()==0 || targetDevice.equals(device.getName()))
                                addDevice(device,rssi);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

As this callback is deprecated, I need a new callback method: **ScanCallBack** to support Lollipop, so I added another callback like this:

```
    mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    Log.i("result", result.toString());
                    BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
                    connectToDevice(btDevice);
                }
            }
        }
     };
```

It can now run in Lollipop, however when I run it on 4.4.2, the app exist unexpected once it run the Class **DeviceListActivity** (all the above is inside this class.) The Log when it failed is:

> 

```
09-02 17:42:46.469 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller D/OLED: Start DeviceListActivity now
09-02 17:42:46.499 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller D/OLED: onPause
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/conerstoneee2/blecaller/DeviceListActivity$3; (63)
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/conerstoneee2/blecaller/DeviceListActivity$3;' failed
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.conerstoneee2.blecaller.DeviceListActivity$3', referenced from method com.conerstoneee2.blecaller.DeviceListActivity.<init>
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1960 (Lcom/conerstoneee2/blecaller/DeviceListActivity$3;) in Lcom/conerstoneee2/blecaller/DeviceListActivity;
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0006
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback;)
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan, referenced from method com.conerstoneee2.blecaller.DeviceListActivity.scanLeDevice
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 311: Landroid/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner;.startScan (Landroid/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback;)V
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0024
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.stopScan, referenced from method com.conerstoneee2.blecaller.DeviceListActivity.scanLeDevice
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 312: Landroid/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner;.stopScan (Landroid/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback;)V
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0041
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner, referenced from method com.conerstoneee2.blecaller.DeviceListActivity.onCreate
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 283: Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter;.getBluetoothLeScanner ()Landroid/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner;
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0071
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.stopScan, referenced from method com.conerstoneee2.blecaller.DeviceListActivity.onDestroy
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 312: Landroid/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner;.stopScan (Landroid/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback;)V
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0014
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.stopScan, referenced from method com.conerstoneee2.blecaller.DeviceListActivity.onStop
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 312: Landroid/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner;.stopScan (Landroid/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback;)V
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0014
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/conerstoneee2/blecaller/DeviceListActivity$3; (63)
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/conerstoneee2/blecaller/DeviceListActivity$3;' failed
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x3ea0 at 0x08 in Lcom/conerstoneee2/blecaller/DeviceListActivity;.<init>
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f8bda0)
09-02 17:42:46.519 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.conerstoneee2.blecaller, PID: 15329
                                                                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.conerstoneee2.blecaller.DeviceListActivity$3
                                                                                 at com.conerstoneee2.blecaller.DeviceListActivity.<init>(DeviceListActivity.java:181)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2289)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 17:42:49.959 15329-15329/com.conerstoneee2.blecaller I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15329 SIG: 9
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks for @Jesse to point out that I can add the code for checking the build version inside the callback. It can build the APK successfully, but now it cannot run in 4.4.2

Comment: AFAIK this is the only way by which you can use the old as well as new API's other way which is not recommended is to reduce the compile and target SDK to min SDK version

Comment: So what kind of exception / error do you get, when you try the first code snippet you posted?

Answer (score 1):

You're close. BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback is an interface. When you do this:

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //String targetDevice = MainActivity.targetDevice.getText().toString();
                                //if(targetDevice==null || targetDevice.length()==0 || targetDevice.equals(device.getName()))
                                addDevice(device,rssi);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

"which is in [your] Activity Class but outside any method." Nothing is really happening with this code. When you call this:

```
mLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
```

and pass it in as a parameter. the mLeScanner uses that callback if and when it is needed.

So, just create your additional callback method (Don't check for the build version).

```
 private **typeNameGoesHere** mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Log.i("result", result.toString());
                BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
                connectToDevice(btDevice);
            }
        }
    };
```

Then keep your startScanBluetooth method as-is and you should be fine.

```
private void startScanBluetooth(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // Method supported in Lollipop
        mLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
    }
    else {
        // Method for older API level
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can add the callback for Lollipop now. Although I still cannot scan the bluetooth device when using an Android 6 device.

Comment: I haven't made any upgrades to 6 yet, but I think the call changed. Check out [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html)

Comment: In the end I found that there is a huge of change in Android 6. I found that I need to get permission in runtime and need to get the  location permission to scan the bluetooth device.

Comment: Also, although now I can build the APK, and the app can run on 6 and 5 without problem, when I run the app on 4, it exists unexpected. I will issue another question so that I can copy the log here.